# Error deploying to render. Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, deployment, render

i dont understand why its giving me the :

```
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

the repo is https://github.com/vstoic/Felp

this is the render log.

```
Jan 27 03:22:46 PM  > Felp@1.0.0 postinstall
Jan 27 03:22:46 PM  > webpack
Jan 27 03:22:46 PM  
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  assets by status 597 KiB [cached] 1 asset
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.94 KiB
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM    ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM    ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js 6.75 KiB [built] [code generated]
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 130 KiB
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM    ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.33 KiB [built] [code generated]
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM    ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js 129 KiB [built] [code generated]
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.33 KiB
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM    ./node_modules/scheduler/index.js 198 bytes [built] [code generated]
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM    ./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js 4.14 KiB [built] [code generated]
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  ./frontend/felp.jsx 945 bytes [built] [code generated]
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  ERROR in ./frontend/felp.jsx 5:0-41
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Components/root.jsx' in '/opt/render/project/src/frontend'
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  resolve './Components/root.jsx' in '/opt/render/project/src/frontend'
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM    using description file: /opt/render/project/src/package.json (relative path: ./frontend)
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM      using description file: /opt/render/project/src/package.json (relative path: ./frontend/Components/root.jsx)
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        no extension
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Components/root.jsx doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        .js
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Components/root.jsx.js doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        .jsx
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Components/root.jsx.jsx doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        *
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Components/root.jsx* doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        as directory
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Components/root.jsx doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  ERROR in ./frontend/felp.jsx 6:0-46
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Store/store.js' in '/opt/render/project/src/frontend'
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  resolve './Store/store.js' in '/opt/render/project/src/frontend'
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM    using description file: /opt/render/project/src/package.json (relative path: ./frontend)
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM      using description file: /opt/render/project/src/package.json (relative path: ./frontend/Store/store.js)
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        no extension
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Store/store.js doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        .js
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Store/store.js.js doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        .jsx
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Store/store.js.jsx doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        *
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Store/store.js* doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM        as directory
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM          /opt/render/project/src/frontend/Store/store.js doesn't exist
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  webpack 5.74.0 compiled with 2 errors in 5126 ms
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  npm ERR! code 1
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  npm ERR! path /opt/render/project/src
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  npm ERR! command failed
Jan 27 03:22:52 PM  npm ERR! command sh -c webpack
```

for it to deploy on render.

i tried changing webpack entry file from index.js to felp.jsx
i added .jsx to the imports for store and root.

not sure how to go about it. project runs correctly on local host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

github changes in file casing don’t always get picked up. Maybe check the file casing in GitHub.